# We did not find any results for "your keyword" SharePoint search 2010

Tags: sharepoint-server, sharepoint-search

I'm working on SharePoint 2010 team site. 
I just want to search anything that contains my keyword. 
but whenever I put something in search box and hit search then it says

> **"We did not find any results for** *your keyword*".

According to different articles found on google, I've set up following things. but still it is not working.

1. Search service application is started on SharePoint server.
2. Search service application proxy is connected.
3. My web application is exist under "**Central Administration**-->**Search Service Application**-->**Content Source**-->**Local SharePoint Site**-->**Start Addresses**.
4. My account has full control permission over my web application.

So, How to resolve this issue?

Comment: Have checked weather your crawling of site content is done or not? If not, then  you need to run crawling of your site, so that your data gets populated in search properties and displays records in result page.

Comment: Thanks Pradip for quick reply. i did not checked that since i don't know how to run crawling on our site. can you please provide any steps or any article link for how to crawl site. looking forward for your reply.. thanks again.

Comment: Here is the MSDN article: https://technet.microsoft.com/en-in/library/ee808864(v=office.14).aspx

Comment: Hello Pradip. As per that MSDN article I've performed crawling on **"Local SharePoint Site"** content source. But it is still not working. Any other solution?